# iPhone 4S iOS 6.1.2 Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> Add New Shortcut not case sensitive

Tags: keyboard, iphone, ios

My custom shortcuts are **not** case sensitive (the opposite was claimed [here](http://www.iphonehelp.org/how-to-define-your-own-keyboard-shortcuts-on-your-iphone.html)).
Example:
Under Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> Add New Shortcut
I specify:
ME : Schorsch
Unfortunately, both `ME` and `me` in the text will be replaced with `Schorsch`. Clearly, the custom shortcut is not case sensitive.
How/where can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the **Shortcut** which is case sensitive, but the **Phrase**. And I don't think making the shortcut so is possible. And here's a reason why. If you enter in the *phrase* section a sentence, or a word, in lowercase, the way you use the *shortcut* will define the way the phrase will appear. Lets clarify this a bit.

Having the shortcut `me: whatever`, writing `Me` will be replaced with `Whatever`, and writing `ME` will be replaced with `WHATEVER`, and, of course, `me` with `whatever`.

This won't work if you've used any capitals in the phrase section, which, therefore, makes a point.

Comment: I cannot confirm that writing ``Me``, ``me`` or ``ME`` makes any difference.

Comment: I tested my self and it works as I said.