# Inconsistent case sensitivity of Text Replacements shortcuts

Tags: macos, ios, input-source, text-input

Edit: related but much more basic (and very old) question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/84503/316790). And the accepted answer doesn't seem (or at least, no longer seems) quite right: They claim if me is a shortcut for name, then Me produces Name, and ME should produce NAME. But this official [image](https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/iOS/ios-16-2-iphone-14-pro-settings-general-keyboard-text-replacement.png) from Apple shows both `GM` for `Good Morning.` and `TTYL` for `Talk to you later.`, meaning case and capitalization of both shortcut and replacement as defined should be/are respected in some way?

I have been trying to get Text Replacements (on both macOS 13.5.2 and iOS 16.6, with shortcuts list synced via iCloud) to work properly in a specific use-case, and it's behaving in a way that makes me question whether it's by design, or indeed a bug. In short, it would appear that the replacement system is inconsistent about how it handles case sensitivity of the shortcuts (the text you type to be replaced).

For a "MRE" à la Stack Overflow: I have \omega as a shortcut for ω, \Omega for Ω, \gamma for γ, and \Gamma for Γ. On macOS, typing \omega and \Omega correctly produces ω and Ω. But typing \gamma and \Gamma produces Γ for both. Meanwhile on iOS, all those shortcuts work correctly, appearing fully case sensitive. Similarly, I have \mathfrakl for  and \mathfrakL for . But on macOS, both shortcuts produce , while on iOS, both produce ! So it would appear to be completely case *in*sensitive, and moreover inconsistent across OSes in which replacement it picks.

This gets further complicated by the auto-capitalization feature (not sure if there's one specific to Text Replacements, or if the general one that also does start of sentences just gets applied simultaneously). If I only have \gamma and not \Gamma as a shortcut, now on macOS, \gamma correctly produces γ, and \Gamma also then auto-capitalizes to Γ without an explicit shortcut. But this does not work with \mathfrakl and \Mathfrakl, both now producing  on both macOS (if I first remove \mathfrakL) and iOS. Presumably it doesn't know that  and  are lower/uppercase variants of the same letter.

**Can an Apple engineer who either worked on or has access to the Text Replacement code, or just someone *really* knowledgeable about this niche feature, chime in to shed some light on this behavior or offer any suggested workarounds?**

Ideally, I would want it to always be fully case sensitive, so I can just always define both(/all) capitalization variants and have it respect my shortcuts exactly. I don't want to rely on the auto-capitalization, which is my current workaround with the Greek letters, because even if it were to learn that  and  are case variants, I also have things like \rightarrow for → and \Rightarrow for ⇒, which would not make sense to consider case variants.

For context, I am trying to get this working with a list of over 1000 shortcuts to type math symbols using LaTeX-like syntax on iOS. See the latest comment [here](https://github.com/DenverCoder1/latex-gboard-dictionary/issues/4) for full details of my testing. I also [asked](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255126880) on Apple Support Communities, but from the answers I've seen on there over the years, they are often... less than helpful for the average power user.

Comment: Related issue that's not major enough to warrant a full question: I have gmadd (short for gmail address) as a shortcut for first.last@gmail.com (with my real name ofc). Whenever I use it on iOS, especially in forms, it automatically types Gmadd by default, and the text replacement + auto-capitalization outputs First.Last@gmail.com instead! So I always have to remember to manually type gmadd (usually by typing g and deleting the G that appears just to type g again). Has anyone run into a similar issue, and/or have a better workaround? I don't want to turn off auto-capitalization globally.

Comment: Capitalizing the last name too, especially after a period with no space, is what really confuses me about the logic behind this design feature. It just seems to me the case sensitivity and auto-capitalization (interplay) aspects of the otherwise really useful Text Replacement feature were not too well thought out or at least not fully tested in real-world use-cases people have for it.

Comment: Re: LaTeX-style Unicode symbol input - On macOS, I already use https://github.com/clarkgrubb/latex-input. Notice how they also had to work around the case sensitivity issue: "The Mac LaTeX input source is case insensitive. In LaTeX, \Delta is used for Δ and \delta is used for δ, but the Mac LaTeX input source will nevertheless insist that you disambiguate. It does this with a pop-up window [like in Chinese or Japanese input sources, for those who know]." Importing the Text Replacements plist in macOS then syncing to iOS via iCloud is the only way to import a list into iOS, afaik

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please add all info in the question and **not** in the comments. One should be able to get the full scope of the issue just by reading the question, without having to trawl through comments as well.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your feedback. I do believe one can get the full scope of the issue just by reading the question, the info in the comments is tangential/optional. I personally didn’t want to make the question too long, because one would simply be “trawling” through that instead.  But if you feel otherwise and suggest I add back all that info as part of the question, I can certainly do so. Alternatively, I can also just delete these comments, because, while I believe they’re interesting and potentially useful as context, again, they’re not necessary for explaining the full scope of the issue.

Comment: Comments are ephemeral in nature and tend to be deleted after a time.

Comment: Understood, thanks for the heads up but that's fine by me in this case